# using twitter as a support url in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

i am developing an app for the app store but it seems i am required to have a support url. I do not have a website dedicated to my app and do not want to make one. Can i use a twitter account dedicated to my app as a support url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html):

> The support website you plan to provide for users who have questions regarding the app. The support URL must lead to actual contact information so that your users can contact you regarding app issues, general feedback, and feature enhancement requests. The URL can specify a localized site.
> Include the entire URL, including the protocol. For example, http://support.example.com .

Make sure whatever page you link to contains that specific contact information.  A good example of this would be a page with an email form or other way to directly contact you.